# Display list within list data in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, listview

```
public class Result()
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public List<ListInfo> Info { get; set; }
}

public class ListInfo
{
    public ListInfo() { }
    public ListInfo(string name, string value)
    {
    Name = name;
    Value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now, on the aspx page, I have the results set to the listview datasource

```
lstResources.DataSource = results;
lstResources.DataBind();
```

and here is the list view:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstResources" runat="server">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
<h4 class="DarkText FontWeightBold"><%# Eval("Title") %></h4>
<p>ID is <%# Eval("ID") %></p>
<asp:Repeater ID="rsInfo" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <h5><%# Eval("Name") %>:</h5>
            <p><%# Eval("Value") %></p>
        </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The title and id are working fine, but I am not able to set the repeater to get the Name and Value values.

Basically, rsInfo has to get the values - Info.Name and Info.Value. And there can be several items in the listinfo. But I am not able to do this. Can you please help?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide DataSource for the repeater, which in your case will be `Info` property in `Result` class, and then use `Eval` on it.
[Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27260/Repeater-within-Gridview-in-C-ASP-NET).